# No effect of activating BOX in axes properties in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, user-interface, plot, border, matlab-guide

I want a box (Border) outside of my `pie3` figure in MATLAB but when I activate (`On`) `Box property` in `axes`, noting will appear. I changed `AmbientLightColor` to black but I have same problem.

How can I draw a black line border for my `pie3` figure in `gui(GUIDE)`?

Thanks.

**Ps.**

Luis Mendo Idea has this effect :

[image]

We have a 3D cube here, not a 2D normal box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, another option to get a 2D border is to make two axes, one for the box & background and the other for your `pie3` call:

```
x = [1,3,0.5,2.5,2]; % Sample data
mainfig = figure;
h_overlayaxes = axes( ...
    'Box','on', ...      % Turn on border
    'Color',[1 1 1], ... % Set your background color
    'Xtick',[], ...      % Turn off x ticks
    'Ytick',[] ...       % Turn off y ticks
    );
h_plotaxes = axes( ...
    'Parent',get(h_overlayaxes,'Parent'), ...     % Match parent figure
    'Position',get(h_overlayaxes,'Position'), ... % Match overlay size & position
    'Color','none' ...                            % Turn off background
    );

pie3(x);
```

Answer (score 3):

The axes are invisible after using `pie3`. You should make them visible:

```
set(gca,'Visible','on')
```

Optionally,

```
set(gca,'Box','on')
```

will add the "outer part" of the axes.

Comment: Thank you for answer. `gca` is referring to `pie3 handle`, `axes handle` or `total figure(window) handle`?

Comment: @user2991243 [`gca`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/gca.html) is a Matlab function that returns the handle to the current _axis_. You can replace it by the axis handle, if you stored it in a variable. Also, note that the axes are in 3D; not sure if that's what you want

Comment: It will likely look 'prettier' to copy the axes before the `pie3` call and clear out the background color so it's overlaying the pie chart with a 2d box instead of a 3d one.

Comment: @excaza Good idea. Not sure how you would "copy the axes", though

Comment: I added output figure and information in main question. Thanks.

Comment: @LuisMendo I think you could use `copyobj` but I usually use a new `axes` call: `h_newaxes = axes('Position',get(h_oldaxes,'Position'),'Color','None','Box','On')` and adjust any other properties I need at once.

Comment: @excaza I see. You should go ahead and write the answer, it was your idea :-)